# A request to undelete my answer

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-answer

My answer to the question [Can an Alcubierre drive be built by starlifting?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/255770/40609) was deleted as not providing an answer to the question. This is factually untrue.

> And since our goal is to help you with an imaginary and, frankly, magical world. Yes, it's possible.
>
> But if what you're asking is whether or not by any stretch of actual science (which means we're ignoring the type 3.5 tech level) it's possible. No, it's not... today.

The tone of my answer may not have met with one's approval, but the question was answered and reasonably so.

- Given the goal of a Kardeshev 3.5 civilization, it's not only possible (as I state) but an Alcubierre drive might realistically be an antique as simple to manufature as a model-T Ford automobile on a modern 3D printer.
- If the requirement of a K3.5 civilization is ignored, then despite @TheRocketFan's comments to the contrary (which demonstrate no factual engineering capability, merely a belief), the answer is still no as the drive itself remains beyond our ability to construct.

If the answer should remain deleted due to its tone, then I would entertain an answer that explains how it violates the Code of Conduct. But if the only legitimate reason for closing the question is a failure to answer it, I request it be undeleted as that is simply untrue.

Answer (score 3):

The answer wasn't deleted because of its tone, it doesn't violate the code of conduct.

It was deleted because it sounds more like an elaborate comment on the question than an actual attempt of answering it: 3 lines out of 12 are quoting our help center, and the rest, plus other citations tangentially helping or not helping at all to answer.

Comment: Is, "this can't be done" not a legitimate answer to the question? Is an attempt to help the OP understand how to use the site better so antithetical to answers that they cannot be a part of them? Or is this a one-vote judgement of the answer's quality? (not that any ca. 2024 science can answer the question yes or no, not with that K3.5 condition).

Comment: @JBH I am fine with an answer that goes more on explaining more the why yes/why no/why whatever you like, it's your story. But it should be more than just copy pasting what the help center says.

Comment: We'll have to disagree on this one, L.Dutch. I quoted the Help Center once and provided links to the Alcubierre Drive, Starlifting, and Clarke's three laws. To be honest, the help center part of it is only a fraction of the whole. If that's all it takes....